# Network check does not work on iOS - Unity

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, networking

I built a mobile game with Unity,
I am using the below code to check every few minutes if there is an internet connection. This code is working very fine on Android, but it does not work on iOS (testFlight), can somebody advice whats wrong? thanks.

```
Public void SetConnectionValiability() 
        => StartCoroutine(CheckConnection((isConnected) => { IsOnline = isConnected; }));

IEnumerator CheckConnection(Action<bool> action)
{
    const string echoServer = "http://google.com";
    bool result;
    using (var request = UnityWebRequest.Head(echoServer))
    {
        request.timeout = 5;
        yield return request.SendWebRequest();
        result = !request.isNetworkError && !request.isHttpError && request.responseCode == 200;
     }
     action(result);
}
```

Also for a commercial game, is it "legal" to ping google like that?

thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to use `https` unless you've allowed arbitrary loads in your plist file. You'll have trouble on Android as well with release versions beyond a certain Android version.

Comment: Before you go too far down this road you might consider how useful the information this gives you is. If your game requires access to a server then that is what is important. If Google was down or blocked and your server was accessible would you want the game to not function properly?

Comment: Thank you for you answer, It is a very valid point that i didn't consider, I've chosen this road because i couldn't find any other way to properly check if the user has connection.. If you have better suggestion please let me know, also thanks for the https thing, it worked.